# XSD Namespace element different to XML namespace allowed?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

im trying to find out whether following case is allowed:

Lets say I have following XSD:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xyz="http://www.example.com/abc" 
targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/abc" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
```

Does the following XML uses the correct namespace? (Please consider the namespace only):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<def:whatever xmlns:def="http://www.example.com/abc">
  <def:adress="Street 1">
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

(StackOverflow doesn't like short answers but I can't think of anything else worth saying.)

Comment: And the opposite answer was already copyrighted. :-) https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2832 Joke aside, @JohnWick: all top-level elements defined in a schema live in its targetNamespace. Since elementFormDefault is set to qualified, the other elements do as well.